# Rails4: Like Button is not working properly (Like limitation )

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a issue with post pages's like/dislike button.

**what i want to do:**

user has lots of Posts and each user can only press 1 like or dislike(cancel like) per post. How can i accomplish this?

**My Issue:**

I can press like button and it shows count 1 like but dislike button is not working(can't cancel the like) . Also post's like limitation is not working properly and i can press 2 or 3 likes for one post(same post).

**Additional statement:**

All posts are sorted by most popular post(number of likes) and it should come to the popular page. so i have popular action to sort posts by most popular posts.

```
   def popular
    @posts = Post.joins(:likes).group(:id).order("count(*) 
    desc").paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 18)
   end
```

**likes table's column:**

user_id, post_id, created_at, updated_at

**posts table's column:**

id, title, content, user_id, created_at, updated_at, picture, category_id, latitude, longitude, address

**Development: sqlite3 production: PostgreSQL**

**post.rb**

```
  class Post < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :category 
    validates :user_id, presence: true
    validates :title, presence: true  
    validates :content, presence: true 
    validates :category_id, presence: true 
    has_many :likes, dependent: :destroy 
    has_many :post_attachments
    attr_accessor :post_attachment_attributes
    acts_as_commontable 
    geocoded_by :address
    after_validation :geocode
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :post_attachments,allow_destroy:true, reject_if: :all_blank

  end
```

**like.rb**

```
  class Like < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :post
    belongs_to :user
  end
```

**likes_controller.rb**

```
   class LikesController < ApplicationController

    def like
     @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
     like = current_user.likes.build(post_id: @post.id)
     like.save
    end

    def unlike
     @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
     like = current_user.likes.find_by(post_id: @post.id)
     like.destroy
    end
   end
```

**_like_links.html.erb**

```
  <% if user_signed_in? %>
    <% if current_user.likes.find_by(post_id: post.id) %>
      <%= link_to (content_tag(:i, '', class: 'fa faheart')),unlike_path(post.id), method: :delete, remote: true %>
      <%=  post.likes.count %> Like
   <% else %>
     <%= link_to (content_tag(:i, '', class: 'fa fa-heart o')),like_path(post.id), method: :post, remote: true %>
   <%=  post.likes.count %>  Like
   <% end %>
   <% else %>
   <%=  post.likes.count %>  Like
  <% end %>
```

**like.js.erb/unlike.js.erb**

```
    $('#like-link<%= @post.id %>').html('<%=escape_javascript(render("likes/like_links", post: @post )) %>');
```

Any help would be appriciate. Thank you for help!!

**After Change Likes controller**

```
    Started POST "/like/25" for ::1 at 2017-05-11 17:29:17 +0900
    Processing by LikesController#like as JS
    Parameters: {"post_id"=>"25"}
    User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE 
    "users"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
    Like Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "likes".* FROM "likes" WHERE 
    "likes"."user_id" = ? AND "likes"."post_id" = ? LIMIT 1  
    [["user_id", 1], ["post_id", 25]]
     (0.1ms)  begin transaction
    SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "likes" ("user_id", "post_id", 
    "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["user_id", 1], 
    ["post_id", 25], ["created_at", "2017-05-11 08:29:18.009414"], 
    ["updated_at", "2017-05-11 08:29:18.009414"]]
     (1.9ms)  commit transaction
    Rendered likes/like.js.erb (35.7ms)
    Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 233ms (ActiveRecord: 17.4ms)
     NoMethodError (undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass):
     app/views/likes/like.js.erb:1:in 
    `_app_views_likes_like_js_erb___3930955212291711879_70111836109880'
```

**Index.html.erb**

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
 <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--6-col">
  <div class="demo-card-square mdl-card mdl-shadow--2dp">
     <div class="category category"><%= link_to post.category.name [post.category.name] %>
     </div>
    <div class="mdl-card__title mdl-card--expand" style="background: url('<%= post.post_attachments.first.picture %>') bottom center no-repeat #fff;">
    <h2 class="mdl-card__title-text"><%= post.title %></h2>
    </div>
  <div class="mdl-card__supporting-text">
    <%= post.content.truncate(120, separator: '.')%>
  </div>
  <div class="mdl-card__actions mdl-card--border">
    <a href="<%= post_path(post.id) %>" class="mdl-button mdl-button--colored mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect" data-upgraded=",MaterialButton,MaterialRipple">
      View more
      <span class="mdl-button__ripple-container"><span class="mdl-ripple"></span></span></a>
    <span id="like-link<%= post.id %>" class="like_box">
      <%= render "likes/like_links", post: post %>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

For restricting multiple likes:

```
class LikesController < ApplicationController
  def like
    current_user.likes.where(post_id: params[:post_id]).first_or_create
  end

  def unlike
    if (like = current_user.likes.find_by_post_id(params[:post_id])).present?
      like.destroy
    end
  end
end
```

A little bit of code refactoring:

```
<% if (user = current_user).present? %>
  if user.likes.find_by(post_id: post.id) %>
    <%= link_to (content_tag(:i, '', class: 'fa faheart')),unlike_path(post.id), method: :delete, remote: true %>
  <% else %>
    <%= link_to (content_tag(:i, '', class: 'fa fa-heart o')),like_path(post.id), method: :post, remote: true %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
<%= post.likes.count %> Like
```

Comment: Hi Md. Thanks for help! I changed Like action but it still same (can not cancel like button & Limitation is not working) .

Comment: is it giving any error? I think in view, it should be `@post.id` instead of `post.id`

Comment: Hi Md! Thanks for advice. i added my index.html.erb . So i have to change the @post.id instead of post.id? Its very helpful if you show me the code.Thanks.